# 2D region plotting with sliders to see how the region changes as parameter varies (Python / plotly / matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I'm a graduate student working in theoretical economics.
I'm a noob plotting in python.
I'm currently writing a paper, and I've found closed form solutions for my equilibrium.
They depend on 3 paramters.

The problem is that there are 3 different types of equilibria, and sufficient conditions that support each equilibrium are determined by 3~5 highly non linear inequalities.

I had used plotly to plot in 3D which parameter values fall in this region determined by inequalities.

My advisor now asks me to plot in 2D with one parameter fixed.
He wants to see how this region bounde with inequalities varies as the fixed parameter varies.
I know Wolfram Mathematica is a good tool to do this, but I've already used the free trial and my university didn't buy mathematica.

Although I've googled a lot, I don't have a clue how to write the code.

Any references, example codes would be very thankful.

Thank You.

I don't have a clue how to even start my code.

Comment: Hi. I only know matplotlib. It comes with a lot of [examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html) and even some ready to use examples for [interactive](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/slider_snap_demo.html) plotting. This might be a good starting point for your exploration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you're using 2D, 2 fixed, and a 3rd variable as an inequality, then you need to use the inequality to control the limits of what is shown in the plot. If it were as simple as x = y  where x > 3, then you could set the limits to x ≥ 3. To get help in Stack Overflow, you need data and programming code. If you want help with theory, approaches, and concepts, even in a specific programming language, it's far better to send your questions to other forums in the Stack Exchange like Cross Validated. Cross Validated was made for these types of questions.